# Change GroupView background on expand (ExpandableListView)

Tags: android, background, expandablelistview, expand, expandablelistadapter

I was searching how to change groupview's background as it expands/collapse. I didn't found my answer, but I solved by simple doing this:

**BaseExpandableListAdapter:**

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderGroup holder;
    if ( convertView == null ){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_cell, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cellNome);
        holder.btCodigo = (ToggleButtonEbrimaBold) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btCodigo);
        holder.tvLancadas = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cellLancadas);
        holder.layoutBackground = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutBackground);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.layoutBackground.setSelected(isExpanded);

    return convertView;
}
```

**ViewHolderGroup**:

```
class ViewHolderGroup {
    TextView tvNome;
    ToggleButtonEbrimaBold btCodigo;
    TextView tvLancadas;
    LinearLayout layoutBackground;
    LinearLayout layoutReceiver;
}
```

**home_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/disciplina_line">

... GroupView content ...

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**disciplina_line.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/line_white"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/line_selected"/>
</selector>
```

I wanted to share this alternative. Hope it helps !